# MATLAB caxis assigning value

Tags: matlab

I have a 3d plot of particles.
I have 500 frames of the motion of these particles.
The frames are received from a 3D matrix that contains position (x,y,z)
Another column in matrix is displacement. Let's say it's column 7 in my 3D matrix.
How can I assign color values based on these displacement values for each particle?

I know about caxis([0 1]), but how does it know which column to look at when determining the color it should be. I have other columns as well. Is there a way to assign this?

Current code:

```
filename = 'testing.gif'
FigHandle = figure('Position', [100, 100, 800, 700]);
for i = 1:499
    s = 2;
    scatter3(ans.atom_data(:,3,i),ans.atom_data(:,4,i),ans.atom_data(:,5,i),s)
    colorbar
    caxis([0,1.61])
    T(i) = getframe
end
```

Comment: What is the range of your displacements?

Comment: Let's just say 0-1.5 (I can edit later)

Comment: OK. Sounds good. What function are you using to plot, so I can be specific about how to set the color?

Comment: Look above, just edited post with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The color is taken from a color map. Most matlab plotting functions allow you to set the color map explicitly. For `scatter3`, you would have to pass in a 5th parameter, called `C`. According to the [mathworks documentation on scatter3](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html):

> If C is a vector with length equal to the length of X, Y, and Z, then
>   the values in C are linearly mapped to the colors in the current
>   colormap.

This means that you can just pass in column 7, with no need to adjust the `caxis`:

```
filename= 'testing.gif'
  FigHandle = figure('Position', [100, 100, 800, 700]);
for i=1:499

    s=2;
    scatter3(ans.atom_data(:,3,i),ans.atom_data(:,4,i),ans.atom_data(:,5,i),s,ans.atom_data(:,7,i))
    colorbar
    T(i)=getframe
end
```

If the default color map is not satisfactory, you can always create your own by passing an `n x 3` array to the [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html) function.

Finally, you should be aware of the fact that the `ans` variable has special meaning in matlab and will change with every statement you run. You may want to store your data into a variable with a different name.